# How to convert data to image in iOS

Tags: ios

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(your_image_here);
```

After that i transferred it to another iPhone using bluetooth.
Now i need to convert the data back to image. Can any one tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is to et back the data which you encoded in the previous question.
For converting `UIImage` to `NSData` ,

```
NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

To get it back,

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:pictureData];
```

Remember to add `[image release]` at the end.

or you can use

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
[image imageWithData:pictureData];
```

Comment: As far as you are not changing the name of the data, you can do it in the same way. But you have to get access to that data, from where it is being stored..

Answer (score 3):

In swift-3 : Data is converted back to image by **:--**

```
        func compressImage() -> UIImage {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named:"background.jpg")!, 0.2)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        return image!
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call `imageWithData:` or on instantiation, you can call `initWithData:`

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)data];
```